# Strange behaviour in views and Controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am having issues trying to work out why my form tag does not work.  I have a pretty standard model with relationships set up.  Within a show view I have

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
            @if (count($project->testing) == 0)
                @include ('projects.partials.testing')
            @else
                @include ('projects.partials.testingEdit')
            @endif

            @if (count($project->data) == 0)
                @include ('projects.partials.data')
            @else
                @include ('projects.partials.dataEdit')
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This basically determines which partial to display, depending on if it has been created yet.  Routes are pretty straight forward

```
Route::model('projects.testing', 'ProjectTesting');
Route::resource('projects.testing', 'ProjectTestingController', ['except' => ['index', 'create', 'show', 'edit', 'destroy']]);

Route::model('projects.data', 'ProjectData');
Route::resource('projects.data', 'ProjectDataController', ['except' => ['index', 'create', 'show', 'edit', 'destroy']]);
```

Within each view, I have a form which takes the following form (in the create views)

```
{!! Form::model(new App\ProjectData, [
       'route' => ['projects.data.store', $project->id]
    ]) 
!!}

//Inputs

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

Both Controllers have a store function.  This is what confuses me.  projects.testing works fine.  I can input data and it is saved to the database.  When I next visit it, the edit view is displayed for this.

The issue is with projects.data.  I can view the create page, and I have outputted data to make sure it is the correct page.  However, if I view the HTML the form is not created

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <input type="hidden" value="h8WsjvIQ0KdiWqIPjCAh3QIDsX1ar86pXvxNgc7y" name="_token">
    //Inputs, but no form tag
</div>
```

If I submit the form, it submits to the update function of the testing controller.  However, if I remove the inclusion of the testing views, the data views/controller works fine.

Am I missing something obvious here?  To me this makes no sense whatsoever why this would be happening?

Thanks

Comment: Can you try replacing `'route' => ['projects.data.store', $project->id]` in your view with `'url' => ['projects-data', $project->id]`, and `Route::resource('projects.data')` with `Route::resource('projects-data')`? Also get rid of the whole except thing, it doesn't do anything in your current setup. I'm trying this because the whole point of using a RESTful controller is so that you don't have to specify specific routes to controller functions

Comment: Doesnt seem to change anything.

Comment: And if you change `Form::model(new App\Projectdata, $array)` to `Form::open($array)`? (With the new routes and url as specified in my first comment)

Comment: Still doesnt show the form for this one.  What's interesting is if I view in inspect element, I do not see the form, only the token.  If I view page source, I see the form element but it's red.

Comment: This usually indicates a tag above the red tag is not opened or closed correctly. Any mistakes with apostrophes or forgotten closing tags?

Comment: Looks like that was the case.  Completely stripped back the code and added things one by one and now it seems to work.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will add as an answer so you can close the question:

The red text in the page source indicates some tag was not opened or closed correctly. Check all tags and apostrophes for something that's not correct and it should work!